# localStorage gets old value when setting it with a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm making a request to my API using `axios` in which I get the profile details.

```
  getProfile(success, error) {
         return axios
          .get("/auth/me/", { headers: this.authHeader() })
          .then(resp => {
                if (resp.status === 200) {
                    success(resp.data)
                } ...and so on..
            })
    }
```

The `authHeader` function basically returns the JWT token, which if it's expired, calls the `refreshToken` function i.e.:

```
authHeader() {
      let token = loadToken()?.access_token // loadToken just loads from localStorage
      if (token ) {
        const epoch = new Date().getTime() / 1000
        const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(icpToken)
        if (decodedJwt.exp <= epoch) {
            this.refreshToken().then(() => {
                return { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + loadToken()?.access_token } // When 
// this is resolved, shouldn't loadToken return the new value, and 
// with that, getProfile should continue with it?
            })
        }
        return { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + loadToken()?.access_token }
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    }

refreshToken() {
    return axios
        .post("/auth/token/refresh/", {"refresh": loadToken()?.refresh_token})
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({
                    ...loadToken(),
                    "access_token": resp.data["access"]
                }))
            }
        })
}
```

The problem with this is that the `getProfile` function get's the old header but I can see it being changed in `localStorage` by `refreshToken`. By my understanding, `refreshToken` should return a `Promise` to `authHeader` which, when resolved, should call the `.then()` and return the new header with the new token.

Comment: Where is loadToken? And not my business but take care when storing user tokens inside the local storage

Comment: `loadToken` is basically just `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(...))`. Could you let me know how should the tokens be stored in localStorage?

Comment: They shouldn't https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#local-storage

Comment: You can use cookies with `httpOnly` to protect from XSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`refreshToken` is asynchronous, but you are using it synchronously. You are calling `this.authHeader()` in a synchronous way, so I think you need to call it like this:

```
async getProfile(success, error) {
  return this.authHeader()
  .then((headers) => {
    return axios.get("/auth/me/", { headers }).then((resp) => {
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        success(resp.data);
      } // ...and so on..
    });
  })
}
```

Also, you need to update `authHeader` to return a promise:

```
async authHeader() {
  let token = loadToken()?.access_token; // loadToken just loads from localStorage
  if (token) {
    const epoch = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(icpToken);
    if (decodedJwt.exp <= epoch) {
      return this.refreshToken().then(() => {
        return { Authorization: "Bearer " + loadToken()?.access_token }; // When
        // this is resolved, shouldn't loadToken return the new value, and
        // with that, getProfile should continue with it?
      });
    }
    return { Authorization: "Bearer " + loadToken()?.access_token };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way around calling `getProfile` with `this.authHeader().then(() => ...)` ?

Comment: you can use async await, but it is asynchronous so you can't use it synchronously.

Comment: But authHeader currently returns a Promise only if the token is expired, what happens if it's not?

Comment: It should really be declared as an asynchronous function so it is expected to return a promise always. It can return a promise even though there is nothing asynchronous to wait for, and will by default if the function is declared as async.

Comment: @WebDev1 Can you hit check to accept the answer if it works for you?